# Including an html element in a Yii2 language string

Tags: internationalization, yii2

Currently we have a string which is translated into several languages. The string requires some formatting around a specific word and as such we're including a span in the translation string.

In the language file...

```
return [
    'signup.success.reminder' => 'This is <span>very</span> important!'
];
```

...and then in the template...

```
<p><?php echo \Yii::t('app', 'signup.success.reminder'); ?></p>
```

Given the above requirement is there a better way to include the span tag?

Comment: I don't think so. You could replace the tags with variables but that doesn't make it better. Or you could remove the span tags and then tell your view to replace defined words ('very') with the word plus the surrounding tags ('<span>very</span>'). This needs be done for each language. But this is also not so elegant... Documentation is [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html) - but you probably know it already.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way if you're not using variables inside the code is putting it all together in the translated string

View

```
<p><?php echo \Yii::t('app', 'This is <span>very</span> important!'); ?></p>
```

Message File

```
return [
    'This is <span>very</span> important!' => 'Esto es <span>muy</span> importante!'
];
```

At least this approach was the one that worked best for me

If you're using complex html, you could replace it like this

View

```
<p><?php echo \Yii::t('app', 'This is {tag} important!', ['tag'=>Html::tag('span'), \Yii::t('app', 'Very'))]; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 a way to doing this is - also mentioned by @nico-savini:

```
<?= Yii::t(
        'app',
        'Welcome to {appName}',
        ['appName' => Html::tag('em', Html::encode(Yii::$app->name))]
    )
?>
```